# Clear Column Data except first Headers |Excel|VBA|

Tags: excel, vba

I want to Delete the Column Data of "A" and "B" on button click => except the First Cell of both the Columns A and B which are **headers**

My Sheet :

[image: Sheet]

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

        Dim myRange As Range
        Set myRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A:B")
        myRange.Clear

   End Sub
```

Clear only Data [except the first Headers of A:B]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long 'declare a long variable to find the last row

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'last row on column A
        Set myRange = .Range("A2:B" & LastRow) 'this way you avoid headers and clear everything
        myRange.Clear
    End With

End Sub
```